# Changing Slider Bar button with the custom button in html5

Tags: html

Is it possible to change slider bar button(for reading numeric values) in any custom button? Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is in webkit:

```
 input[type="range"]{
   -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 }

 input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
   -webkit-appearance:none !important;  
 }
```

You can then add whatever attributes you need to each those selectors. Background, gradient, etc...

Hope that helps!

See this link as well: http://webstutorial.com/range-input-slider-html5-css3/html-5